# MVC TDD : How to write test for Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, response.redirect

I am new to MVC and TDD, so if it is a stupid question please spare me :)

What I am trying to do is , I have created a SignOn controller and I just want to write a Test for that controller. The thing is SignOn controller does Response.Redirect internally, that works fine if it is an proper request, but when I run my test it fails as there is no response object.

so how can I test my SignOn controller, which redirects internally ??

Answer (score 3):

When you want to do a redirect you should use the actionresult: `Redirect("url")`. In your test you can check if the actionresult is of type RedirectResult and/or if it has the right property values.

Comment: I tried Redirect("url") initially , but I guess it was doing nothing it was not redirecting to my home page, thats why I moved to Response.Redirect("url").

Answer (score 1):

Your action method should return a [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx).  If you know exactly what the URL should be, you can test the `Url` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a TDD guy but something tells me that HttpContextBase is your friend : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx

Here is a good resource on that.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/07/16/using-moq-to-mock-asp-net-mvc-httpcontextbase.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, HttpContextBase is something to stay clear of in actions if you want testable controllers. It's not trivial to create a properly working mockup for HttpContext and it needlessly complicates the test. In general the best approach is to let interaction with HttpContext be handled by the appropriate action result, in this case Redirect or RedirectToAction.

Comment: I agree with Marnix, HttpContextBase makes my test too much complex, Infact MVC 3 projects templates by default have these implemented. I had remove these from my project, my project is not so big that I require so complex test, but definitely go for these kind of test once my application goes big.

Answer (score 0):

One of the patterns you can use for testing navigation code inside a controller/presenter is the ApplicationController.

Have a look at the following description[PEAA: Application Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html)

We have implemented the Aplication Controller in our ASP.NET app.

```
ApplicationController.Navigate(view: "LoginScreen", argument: userId);
```

The ApplicationController checks which NavigationWorkflows are registered and delagetes the navigation to the correct class.

In your unit tests you can mock the NavigationWorkflow with something like rhino mocks and pass this to your ApplicationController. Then you can check if the correct navigation methods are called on your workflow.

So instead of calling Response.Redirect, you delegate the navigation responsibility to a separate class that can be replaced with unit testing.

Comment: I Was thinking of making a separate class of this, but it is like I need Response.Redirect just this one time, I couldn't think of any other scenarios where I will have to use Response.redirect instead of RedirectToAction , so I didnt followed this approach I was afraid of doing over engineering.